# How to open temporary definition dialog in easyui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-easyui

In my project, I use easyUI dialog.

At frist, I defined dialog in oa.php page directly, just like:

```
<div id="assDlg" class="easyui-dialog" title="associateDlg" closed="true" modal="true" style="width:1000px;height:600px;top:130px;left:400px">
<div class="easyui-layout" style="position:static;height:15%;width:100%" data-options="region:'north',title:'',split:true"> 
</div>
<div class="easyui-layout" id="assSDiv" style="position:static;height:85%" data-options="region:'south',title:'',split:true">
    <table id="assTB"  title="" class="easyui-datagrid" ></table>
</div>
</div>
```

But when assDlg dialog is closed with:

```
 $('#assDlg').dialog('destroy');
```

And then I want to open this dialog with:

```
 $('#assDlg').dialog('open');
```

It fails. It shows nothing.

So I search the answer to this question with google, and I find that easyui dialog can not be defined in page directly.

A closed dialog can be opened again, but a destroyed dialog can't. After destroying a dialog, this dialog no longer exists, the user can't do anything on it again.

And I try another way to close it with:

```
$('#assDlg').dialog.('close');
```

But it is confused when it is opened more than twice.

Someone in google suggest temporary definition of dialog with :

```
$('<div></div>').dialog({  
id:"assDlg",    
title:"associateDlg",  
top:130,
left:400,
width: 1000,      
height: 600,      
closed: false,      
cache: false,      
href:'assDocDlg.php',   
modal: true,  
onClose:function(){  
    $(this).dialog('destroy');  
    }  
});
```

The content of assDocDlg.php is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height:100%">
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="easyui-layout" style="position:static;height:15%;width:100%" data-options="region:'north',title:'',split:true">    
</div>
<div class="easyui-layout" id="assSDiv" style="position:static;height:85%" data-options="region:'south',title:'',split:true">
    <table id="assTB"  title="" class="easyui-datagrid" ></table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But when it is opened with:

```
$('#assDlg').dialog('open');
```

It fails again. It seems nothing wrong of temporary definition of dialog.

who can help me ?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to avoid this problem:

```
var tbStr='<table id="assTB"  title="" class="easyui-datagrid" ></table>';
$("#assSDiv").html(tbStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should close your dialog (not destroy) if you want to reopen it.

I tried your code and closing and reopening works fine.

```
<div style="margin:20px 0;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" onclick="$('#assDlg').dialog('open')">Open</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="easyui-linkbutton" onclick="$('#assDlg').dialog('close')">Close</a>
</div>

<div id="assDlg" class="easyui-dialog" title="associateDlg" closed="true" modal="false" style="width:1000px;height:600px;top:130px;left:400px">
    <div class="easyui-layout" style="position:static;height:15%;width:100%" data-options="region:'north',title:'',split:true"> 
    </div>
    <div class="easyui-layout" id="assSDiv" style="position:static;height:85%" data-options="region:'south',title:'',split:true">
        <table id="assTB"  title="" class="easyui-datagrid" ></table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I had tried this way, and it opened ok. But when i opend second time and called : var getItems = $("#assTB").datagrid("getChecked"); The value of getItems is incorrect for closing way is just hidden dialog.

Comment: So you got a problem with grid when you reopen the dialog. Now I get it. When I have time i will look through it too.

Comment: Sorry. I couldn't reproduce your problem. :/ Everything seems fine on my side. But I am not using PHP I am testing everything static so I think we are not on the same page.